# convergence in $L^r(I)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I=(0, 1)$. Suppose we are given $1<p<+\infty$ and a sequence of function $f_n$ which is bounded in $L^p(I)$. I was thinking.. if we also assume that $f_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^1(I)$, can we conclude that $f_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^r(I)$, at least for $1\leq r<p$?

Many thanks

Guido

Comment: Do you mean that $\|f_n\|_p$ is bounded, or the functions $f_n$ are bounded (uniformly, presumably) and in $L^p$?

Comment: $\|f_n\|_p$ is bounded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\|f_n\|_r^r\leqslant\|f_n\|_p^{p(r-1)/(p-1)}\cdot\|f_n\|_1^{(p-r)/(p-1)}\leqslant C\cdot\|f_n\|_1^{(p-r)/(p-1)}\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0
$$

Comment: Very succinct...

Answer (score 1):

More generally (than the answer by did), given $1\le p,q<\infty$, any $r$ strictly between $p$ and $q$ can be written
$$r=\frac{p}{s}+\frac{q}{s'},\qquad\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s'}=1.$$
Then
$$\def\abs#1{\lvert#1\rvert}\def\norm#1{\lVert#1\rVert}
  \int\abs{f}^r=\int\abs{f}^{p/s}\cdot\abs{f}^{q/s'}
  \le\norm{f^{p/s}}_s\cdot\norm{f^{q/s'}}_{s'}
  =\norm{f}_p^{p/s}\cdot\norm{f}_q^{q/s'},
$$
so you can generalize the problem (and did's solution) by replacing $1$, $p$ by $p$, $q$.